# Дополнительные права пользователю с Apache

Tags: php, apache, debian

Если запускать *Wkhtmltopdf* из консоли под root, то все отлично работает.

Если переключиться на пользователя, из-под которого работает сайт и PHP, то при запуске *Wkhtmltopdf* выдает `Segmentation fault`.

При этом, если прописать `su` и пароль *root-а*, то при запуске *Wkhtmltopdf* все работает отлично.

Как я понимаю, пользователю не хватает прав, чтобы *Wkhtmltopdf* нормально функционировал.

Как расширить права пользователю?

Comment: выясните причину ошибки. тогда и станет понятно, как её устранить.

Answer (score 1):

правильный путь: выяснить (и устранить) причину ошибки.

путь же предоставления неограниченных прав пользователю, от имени которого работает *http-сервер* — неверен и опасен.

---

если вы всё это осознаёте и согласны с дырой в безопасности, то можете предоставить пользователю, от имени которого работает *http-сервер* (вероятно, *www-data*), право выполнять нужную команду от имени пользователя *root* без ввода пароля.

для этого добавьте в `/etc/sudoers` (редактировать его следует с помощью программы *visudo*) строку:

```
www-data  ALL=NOPASSWD: /путь/к/программе
```

тогда от имени этого пользователя можно будет выполнять команду вида:

```
$ sudo /путь/к/программе [опции|параметры]
```