# Как запустить Python скрипт с root-правами без ввода пароля?

Tags: python, linux, root, sudo

Есть скрипт на Python, который с помощью `subprocess.call()` запускает команду из терминала, но для выполнения этой команды требуются root-права и, соответственно, если добавить `sudo`, запрашивается пароль.

Как выдать root-права без ввода пароля, чтобы скрипт мог выполняться в фоне и вообще не требовал вмешательства пользователя?

Уточню, что требуется запускать `sudo` без пароля только для скрипта, а не для всей системы.

Фрагмент кода:

```
def check_updates():
     """
         Check updates, return amount of available to update packages.
         Otherwise (if no updates available) return 0 (zero).    
     """

     # Sync local package database with an online mirror
     subprocess.call(['sudo','pacman', '-Syy'])

     output = subprocess.check_output(['pacman', '-Qqu'])

     # Return updates number because each package name ends with "\" character
     output = str(output).count('\\')
     return output
```

Добавил это в `/etc/sudoers.d/`, но не помогло.

```
alexleet ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /home/alexleet/projects/update-notifier/update-notifier.py
```

Скрипт запускаю из консоли так: `sudo ./update-notifier`

Comment: @MaxU решение из этого топика помимо запуска скрипта без ввода пароля позволяет всегда использовать `sudo` без подтверждения. Это неэтично и небезопасно, как мне кажется.

Comment: @MaxU ума не приложу почему, но это не работает. Все равно просит пароль при запуске.

Comment: фактически дубликаты: [1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/458610/178576), [2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/552212/178576), [3](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/968175/178576) и т.д. и т.п.

Comment: @MaxU `./название_скрипта.py`, а `sudo` у меня стоит в вызове команды из `subprocess.call()`

Comment: @MaxU конечно, извиняюсь. Обновил, думаю, теперь станет понятнее.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых старайтесь всегда использовать полные пути - хотя бы до того момента, пока не убедитесь, что все работает:

```
output = subprocess.check_output(['sudo', '/path/to/pacman', '-Qqu'])
```

Во-вторых в `/etc/sudoers` должна быть прописана программа, которую вы запускаете с предикатом `sudo` (NOTE: не забываем о полных путях):

```
alexleet ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /path/to/pacman
```